# Сендер почты по расписанию

Tags: laravel, email, php8

проект таск-менеджер, стоит следующая задача: необходимо сделать сендер-напоминалку за день до окончания задачи на почту пользователя. Примерный алгоритм:

1. Задача создаётся с полем id и deadline, летит в очередь
2. Шедулер подхватывает значение deadline и высчитывает дату как deadline - date.now + 24h и когда этот момент настает, вызывает сендер с данными задачи (задачу нужно отобразить в письме в таком виде, в каком и на сайте)
3. Удаление задачи с очереди и шедулера

Если я правильно понял алгоритм, подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать это

Answer (score 0):

1. Зачем задача летит в очередь? Она просто хранится в бд.
2. Как вариант, шедулер раз в час запускает джоб на проверку задач по которым нужно разослать уведомления о дедлайне.

```php
$scheduler->job(new CheckForTaskDeadlinedJob())->hourly();
```

В джобе берешь задачи по которым нужно отправить уведомление. Если важно уведомить только один раз, то можно добавить флаг о том что уведомление уже было отправлено.

```php
function handle() {
    Task::whereDate('deadline_at', '<', now()->addDay())
        ->each(fn(Task $task) => dispatch(new TaskDeadlinedNotification($task)));
}
```

3. Джоб с уведомлением отправляет письмо, в нем можно отправить задачу как view файл.

Если что-то не понятно, спрашивай

Comment: Получается очередь хранит ссылку на джобу в БД, а джоба в свою очередь это сам метод отправки письма? И еще вопрос, классы нотификаторов это аналог класса Mail? Тогда джоба не метод отправки письма, а собирает задачи, и отправкой на почту занимается TaskDeadlinedNotification. Рассуждением вышел на кое решение, но оставлю ход мыслей, правильный ли он?

Comment: Да, в джоб отправляется модель при отправке уведомления. Это второй джоб который отправляет уведомление, он уже ничего не проверяет. А первый джоб занимается тем что периодически проверяет все задачи - не нужно ли по какой-либо отправить уведомление. 
Да, можно Mailable джоб просто сделать на отправку. Ход мыслей верный

Comment: Спасибо большое, решил правда использовать Мейл фасад. А метод WithoutOverlapping не спасает от уведомления больше одного раза?

Comment: Нет, джоб же быстро отрабатывает и все. А проверки каждый час (условно). Я бы флаг использовал для надежности

Comment: Понял. Спасибо большое за разъяснения. Также благодарю за ответ на второй вопрос)